# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings Spring Maven

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, logging, slf4j

After adding apache.mahout to my pom.xml I started to have this warning when i run my spring project and i want to know how supress this warning.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Kapio/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Kapio/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.30/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

This is my pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
            <artifactId>mahout-mr</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried to exclude slf4j-log4j12 but still not working and having the warning everytime

```
<exclusions>
   <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>        
   </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

i looked everywhere and i couldn't remove the warning.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a full working example of that on GitHub/GitLab/Bitbucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to find out *who* pulls in slf4j-log4j. Do a "mvn:dependency:tree" on the command line in your pom.xml directory and find the dependency that pulls it in.
2. Put the exclusion on that dependency. Global exclusions don't work.
3. That should work.

Comment: Thank you ,i didn't run mvn:dependency:tree but i knew that mahout is using it so i excluded it from dependency apache.mahout.